# Hindu traditional book about people skills, making friends and influencing people

Tags: scripture, book-recommendation

Is there a Veda, Puran,Aagama or any ancient Indian book that talks about how to manage people in an organization, make friends and influence people?

Comment: yes the Ramayana and the Bhagavata Purana

Comment: I am looking for specific texts in the form of Sutras that give specific advice. For instance, Niti Shashtra give specific Do's and Don'ts. Another example would be Kamasutra, but instead of influencing romantic partners it should talk about influencing people to like, respect and obey. Ramayana and Bhagavata Purana broad story based text from which such information can be inferred.  I am looking for a traditional version of a book like "How to win friends and influence people - by Dale Carnegie"

Comment: Not sure if any explicit such Hindu scripture exists. All Sanskit texts are not Hindu texts (Kamasutra, Niti Sastra, Artha Sastra..so on), i mean, these texts don't belong to Hindu Dharma or Hinduism.

Comment: Yudhishtira answers this in a simple question asked by Yaksha : "How to become dear to everyone". Answer : "Give up your ego". Proof - everyone loves children.

Comment: I have been reading the Ramcharitmanas. I noticed an interesting manner in which people address a listener. Before addressing any person define the attributes of the listener so as to stimulate a certain aspect of the listener's personality over other aspects. Influencing people can be achieved by using this technique. What do you think?